# Spring message source, getMessage in bean XML?

Tags: java, spring

I have set up my resources like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>locale\\messages</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

My propertyFile:

```
battle.name=TestBattle
```

I would like to reach the text "TestBattle" when I use a bean:

```
<bean id="battlefield" class="com.mypackage.Battlefield" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="battle.name" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="armies" />
</bean>
```

I want to refeer the message in the propertyFile in this line

```
<constructor-arg index="0" value="battle.name" />
```

Is there a way to do it without going into java using the

```
getMessage("battle.name",...
```

code in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least, you could use spel to do it.

for example

```
<bean id="messageSourceAccessor" class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="battlefield" class="com.mypackage.Battlefield" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{messageSourceAccessor.getMessage('battle.name')}" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="armies" />
</bean>
```

However it seems cumbersome if you have to translate many codes.

Other option is using a `String` to `String` `PropertyEditor` to do the translation.

```
public class MessageSourcePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor;

    public MessageSourcePropertyEditor(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSourceAccessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String value = text;

        if (text.startsWith("i18n:")) {
            value = messageSourceAccessor.getMessage(text.substring(5));
        }

        setValue(value);
    }
}

public class MessageEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new MessageSourcePropertyEditor(messageSource));

    }

    public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        return messageSource;
    }

    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }
}
```

And use the prefix **i18n:** to translate codes, ie

```
<bean id="propertyEditorConfigure" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
        <list>
            <bean class="message.MessageEditorRegistrar">
                <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="battlefield" class="com.mypackage.Battlefield" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="i18n:battle.name" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="armies" />
</bean>
```