# Spring Unit Test Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to test Spring MVC Controller but i have some problems. I will copy the stack trace for more clear explanation. I think that the problem comes form applicationContext configuration but i do not know how to fix it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'audioCaptchaServlet': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor profiles.captcha.AudioCaptchaServlet.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'msa' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.buildApplicationContext(TestContext.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor profiles.captcha.AudioCaptchaServlet.msa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'msa' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'msa' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 44 more
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.profiles" />

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="msa"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor"></bean>

    <bean id="audioCaptchaServlet" class="profiles.captcha.AudioCaptchaServlet"></bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Well, without your configuration, no one can help you.

Comment: My initial feel about the problem is that you have configured some incompatible library with Spring.

Comment: @Kashif Nazar how to check that ?

Comment: As stated by the error message: [`MessageSourceAccessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceAccessor.html) needs a `MessageSource` (was the case in 2.5.6)

Comment: @rocker - What are the libraries you are using?

Comment: @RC i do not understand you.

Comment: @Kashif Nazar this are the libraries that i use - fest-assert-1.4, hamcrest-all-1.3, hamcrest-core-1.3, hamcrest-library-1.3, javax.servlet-api-3.0.1, junit-4.4, mockito-all-1.9.5, mockito-core-1.9.5, spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE, spring-test-2.5, spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: As RC said above, you need to provide a constructor argument for MessageSourceAccessor -- the stack trace is quite informative -- it tells you that you can't make a MessageSourceAccessor without one. In this case it requires a message source as a constructor arg. There's an example in the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336290/spring-message-source-getmessage-in-bean-xml

Comment: @Engineer Dollery i can not add a constructor because i use MessageSourceAccessor  as Autowired field.

Comment: Sorry, that's just not correct. Try again, this time take a look at the first answer in the link I sent :)

Answer (score 2):

`MessageSourceAccessor` is a helper class for easy access to messages from a `MessageSource`, providing various overloaded getMessage methods. It doesn't have default constructor with zero argument. This bean is depends on `MessageSource` bean, which can be register as below.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>#Path to properties files#</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then inject this reference to `MessageSourceAccessor` through constructor injection.

```
<bean id="msa"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor">
  <constructor-arg ref="messageSource"> 
</bean>
```